# How to bind a search function into a v-select?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to add a search function in a v-select and I have tried to view the sample online and I applied on my code but it fail to work.

[image]

My code here:

```
<v-flex v-if="isShow2==true">
        <v-container>
          <h3>{{$translate('search_kol_shop_name')}}</h3>  
          <v-autocomplete
            :items="merchant_list"
            :filter="customFilter"
            item-value="yippi_inbox"
            item-text="yippi_inbox"
            label="KOL Shop Name"
            multiple
            v-model="updateQuery"
            @input="startMethod"
          >
          </v-autocomplete>
        </v-container>
      </v-flex>
```

My scripts code :

```
export default {
   data(){
      return {
        product:'',
        isShow1: false,
        isShow2: false,
        shop_name:'',
        merchant_list: [],
        updateQuery: [],
        multiple: false,
        searchTerm: ""
      }
    },
    props:[
       'props'
    ],
    computed:{
    r(){
       return this.props
    },
  },
   methods:{
    customFilter(item, queryText, itemText) {
      const textOne = item.yippi_inbox.toString().toLowerCase()
      const textTwo = item.abbr.toString().toLowerCase()
      const searchText = queryText.toString().toLowerCase()
      return textOne.indexOf(searchText) > -1 || textTwo.indexOf(searchText) > -1
      //console.log("Done : ", textOne.toString().toLowerCase());
    },
    startMethod(event){
      this.updateQuery = event
      this.saveEndorsement();
    },
    getMerchantList(){
        var self = this;
        axios.get("/api/merchant/promote/getPromoteMerchant")
        .then(response => {
           this.merchant_list = response.data
        })
      },
    }
```

The error that I got is :

[image]

My expected Result will be like this :

[image]

Is it instead of v-autocomplete, any other search function can be apply into a v-select environment?
If anyone of you would help much appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your working code on codesanbox?

Comment: @StarkButtowski Ya, sure. https://codepen.io/beckywei/pen/NWxLPMx